# Unity - emit particles to target position (with gravity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles, projectile

I created a particle effect with parabolic movement just like the arrow projectile, is there any way to predict the particles start speed so that I can control which position they will fall on to ?

Comment: Missing code snippets, examples and/or not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes

In the Inspector of your particle system there should be a parameter for the start speed named "Start Speed". It is public and you can even reference it through script.